# How to incorporate SSRS report into a desktop application without changing the UI code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services, crystal-reports

Currently, at work we use CrystalReports to create reports for clients. We are trying to see if it would easier to use SSRS instead.

Basically, we have a stored procedure in our report with parameters that is used to generate a report. We have a desktop application that our clients can use enter the parameters -> This application has access to our SQL server that has a table with a url -> the web server runs a c# code that feeds the parameters to crystal report -> the crystal reports is generated in the web server -> the report is then displayed on our desktop application

Is there a way to use SSRS instead to do this without changing our desktop application code? Any other ideas on how to generate a report in an application using other tools?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You will almost certainly have to make some changes to your desktop application code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a web browser tool in visual studio, In toolbar you can find Web Browser Tool. For the relevant reporting module use a web browser and you will be able to work on ssrs without changing any codes. Here what you requested

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154537.aspx